# enter a string of characters, the Latin lowercase letters turn capital letters and the rest of

Tags: assembly, x86

Enter a string of characters, the Latin lowercase letters turn capital letters and the rest of the characters switch back only not even-numbered places in binary code and display.

OUTPUT MUST BE 'CБCBD'
BUT OUTPUT IS THIS IMAGE
[image: RUN .EXE]

THE CODE THIS

```
DOSSEG                                    ;segment sequencing directive
.MODEL SMALL                              ;directive of the model of code 
                                           ;and data of the near type
.STACK 200H                               ;a 512-byte stack
.DATA                                     ;start of the data
STRING DB 'c~cbd$'                        ;string
STRING_LENGTH EQU $-STRING                ;string length=6 in this example 
STRING1 DB STRING_LENGTH DUP (?) , '$'    ;another string1,has the same 
                                           ;length
.CODE                                     ;start of the code
MOV AX,@DATA                              ;access to the data segment
MOV DS,AX                                 ;access to the data segment
XOR SI,SI                                 ;SI set to zero
XOR DI,DI                                 ;DI set to zero

MOV CX,STRING_LENGTH                      ;put string length into CX,for 
                                           ;looping 6 times

S:                                        ;breakpoint S

MOV BL,STRING[DI]                         ;remember current element of 
                                            ;string into BL
AND STRING[DI],11100000B                  ;checking if the current element 
                                           ;of string is lowercase
CMP STRING[DI],01100000B                  ;checking if the current element 
                                           ;of string is lowercase
JNE L1                    ;if the current element of string 
                           ;is lowercase is not equal 
                           ; go to the breakpoint L1 otherwise go to inside

XOR BL,00100000B               ;remember current element of string into BL 
                            ; (lowercase letters) convert to capital letters 
MOV STRING1[SI],BL             ;put the current capital letter into string1

ADD SI,2                 ;increment by 2 (because the size of SI is 2 bytes) 
                           ; to go to the next item of string1
ADD DI,2                 ;increment by 2 (because the size of DI is 2 bytes)  
                           ;to go to the next item of string

LOOP S                                ;cycle,go to the breakpoint S

L1:                                   ;breakpoint L1
XOR STRING[DI],01010101B          ;Switch the current element of string back 
                                    ;to only non-even places
MOV AL,STRING[DI]                 ;put the current element into register AL
MOV STRING1[SI],AL                ;put the current element into string1

ADD SI,2                 ;increment by 2 (because the size of SI is 2 bytes) 
                           ; to go to the next item of string1
ADD DI,2                 ;increment by 2 (because the size of DI is 2 bytes)  
                           ; to go to the next item of string

LOOP S                                    ;cycle,go to the breakpoint S

XOR DX,DX                                 ;DX set to zero
LEA DX,STRING1                            ;download executive address
MOV AH,09H                                ;DOS line output function
INT 21H                                   ;display changed characters
MOV AH,4CH                              ;DOS function of program termination
INT 21H                                   ;finish the program
END
```

I USE TURBODEBBUGER  TO SEE WHAT HAPAND BUT CANT FIND THE PROBLEM
[image: AFTER RUNNING PROGRAM USING F9]

I SEARCH IN STACKOVERFLOW,GOOGLE BUT CANT FIND THE CURRENT PROBLEM .
CAN YOU HELP ME TO SOLVE THIS

Comment: Why are you incrementing your string indices by 2? `add si, 2` for instance should be `add si,1` (or `inc si`). Your comment regarding why you're using 2 doesn't make sense.

Comment: because the size of SI is 2 bytes

Comment: Yes, `si` is two bytes, but you only want to add 1 to it because you want to address your strings one byte at a time. It doesn't make sense to add 2 to `si` just because `si` is a 2-byte value. If you add 2, then you are skipping every other byte in your string. The microprocessor is smart enough to know how to increment a 16-bit register by 1.

Comment: 'STRING ' is 'DB' thats why we must to add 1?

Comment: but it doesnt solve the problem

Comment: Yes, `db` is "bytes". That may not be all of your problem, but it's still a problem.

Comment: The other problem is that your first `loop s` falls through to `L1` when it's done. That's not good. Right after your first `loop s` you need to jump down to the `xor dx,dx`, right after your second `loop s`. The code overall needs some significant restructuring. You should write it so you need only one `loop s` and you can do your character manipulations more efficiently as well.

Comment: thanks will know that  do not need to do this, it slows down the program and it's not good, but the problem I think is not this, because I wrote several programs with one LOOP but always on the black screen there were these garbage.

Comment: after `mov ds,ax` at the very beginning of the code, switch by tabulator to the memory view (bottom sub-window), and do Ctrl+G and enter `ds:0` to see your original string (`0`, because `OFFSET STRING` is also zero, I'm not sure if you have debug symbols in the executable, then `ds:STRING` may work, but I never bothered with debug info myself, I did always read the addresses back from the disassembly code) ... then do just first `and` + `cmp` instructions to see how you already destroyed the source string data.

Comment: You need to fix your logic, that after the modification loop the final result in memory looks like `<some bytes representing characters> 24` .. the value 0x24 is `'$'` in ASCII encoding, which is string terminator for the `int 21h, ah=9` service. Without that terminator the `int 21h` will output many characters, before it will run into the `$` character by accident. So you can check `ds:STRING1` memory view to see what you are going to output and where it will stop. (BTW the memory view shows on left side bytes as hexa numbers, on right are ASCII symbols, so string should be readable there)

Comment: *"the Latin lowercase letters turn capital letters and the rest of the characters switch back only not even-numbered places in binary code"* - I don't understand this task BTW ... lowercase to capital is clear, but I'm not sure about the rest. Maybe create some table with example of which value should be converted to what. Also your "length" definition includes the dollar char, so inside your loop logic that dollar is valid input character, part of the string to be processed.

Comment: I did not understand the first message, I understood only that at first I need to fix the logic, I write the $ character separately, so that it does not count as a string character, I'm familiar with ASCII code and about your question, for example we have 00001001 when xor changes, bits that are in odd places, result 01011100

Comment: first message about memory view? On your screenshot the bottom-left window panel shows values at address `4644:0000`, which is maybe PSP area, or something... switch by pressing "TAB" key to that panel and use Ctrl+G to enter new address, like `ds:si`, etc... to watch memory there. (of course after you did set `ds` to `@data` and cleared `si` to something meaningful) ... also the TD.EXE will clear all registers upon the start of the code, while the DOS will **NOT**, so make sure you use only initialized registers, don't count on some register to contain zero after execution start.

Comment: Ok,i understood what are you talking about,i think i must read more books ,thank you very much,now my question is answered,thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is basically main loop like this:

```
  ... (set DS, etc)
  mov  cx,STRING_LENGTH
  xor  si,si
processString:
  ; si = index of character to process
  ; cx = characters to process
  mov  al,STRING[si]   ; al = source character
  cmp  al,'a'
  jb   not_lowercase_letter
  cmp  al,'z'
  ja   not_lowercase_letter
  ; lowercase letter in AL detected, make it capital
  and  al,11011111B ; clear the 0x20 bit
  jmp  store_final_character
not_lowercase_letter:
  xor  al,01010101B ; flip the bits on odd positions
store_final_character:
  mov  STRING1[si],al
  inc  si
  loop processString
  ... (output result)
```

What you should learn from this piece of code (if you manage to make it work):

- the memory is accessed only when it's impossible to avoid it, i.e. the character value is loaded from STRING once, and written into STRING1 once. There's never instruction like `XOR STRING[SI],55h` and then further manipulation with such memory value. Memory access is much slower than operations done on registers only, so as long as you have multiple operations to do, it's usually better to move the value from memory into register, do all the calculation over it, and then store the final result back into memory.
- because the STRING is converted to STRING1 in 1:1 mapping (one input character does produce one output character), I use only one index in `si`, not two identical indices in `si`+`di`.
- I test for the latin lowercase letter exactly ('a' to 'z' values range only), your bit-mask test can mistake characters like `{` for lowercase letter, see ASCII table definition to understand how the characters are encoded, and do test-calculation with some of them to see yourself how they will turn out.
- I have single code-path for beginning and end of the loop body. I use `jmp` from the lowercase letter code-path to skip the non-lowercase middle part, and rejoin back into the shared code of storing modified character. This saves me from duplicate lines storing result and incrementing index and two `loop` instructions.
- use meaningful label names. `S` doesn't mean anything and it will become very cryptic and hard to understand to other readers of source code. With IBM PC computer operating with 640kB of basic RAM there was no need to save memory by using short labels, like we did on 8 bit computers with 16-64kB of RAM, where just fitting assembler + source code + compilation result into the memory was quite an achievement, and one had often to split the source code into several smaller parts, being compiled separately, and then before testing them you had to drop the assembler and source from memory and load the compiled machine code. (this is a voice from 1988, today you have GIGA bytes of memory, you will never write long enough source code in your whole life to even marginally fill the current computer RAM). So if it was already in 1988 possible to use meaningful label names, use them also today.

Comment: If you use `bl` instead of `al`, you could use `lea ax, [bx-'a']` / `cmp al, 'z'-'a'` / `ja not_lowercase_letter`.  Fewer instructions (and faster on modern CPUs without partial-reg stalls), but overall code-size suffers from XOR and `and bl,imm8` taking 3 bytes instead of 2 for AL.

Comment: `jmp` is costly too. You could easily avoid `jmp store_final_character` with `and al, 11011111b` `xor al, 01010101b` `xor al, 01010101b`. The 2 `xor`s cancel each other out.